# My tiptap bubble_menu works, but it also does a form submission when the menu item is clicked

Tags: tiptap

For example, I was using this:

```
<button  onclick="editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()">
```

But I got the solution from the kind folks on the discord server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the menu item, specify type=button  (otherwise browser might think it's a submit button type)

```
<button type=button  onclick="editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()">
```

Comment: There may be few of us using TipTap 2 but I was very thankful that you posted this solution.

Comment: Thank you! So obvious in hindsight